# jQuery Mobile - NO CSS applied on Android browsers

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, android-browser

i have tried to prepare some "demo" site using jquery mobile.

Everything works perfect on my iPhone with Safari, Google Chrome, Dolphin Browser.
On my desktop it also works great 1 : 1 like on iPhone.

If i want to test it on my collegue's Samsung Galaxy Ace with Android, there are no CSS styles
in native android browser, also in Dolphin browser.

I have also tested several web emulators like: http://www.howtogomo.com/en/d/test-your-site/#gomo-meter
And the result was the same.. the site has all the elements, but no CSS styles have been applied.

I use this stylesheet definition in the  element:  
I had to add some other styles so i copied them in the end of this file.

Here is my demo site: http://soundart.cz/mobile/index.php

Thanks a lot for your help!
Btw. i have tested some sites from your jqmgallery.com and it works fine with CSS on the same android browser. But i cannot find the differences between other sites and mine :(

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly jQuery 1.7.2 isn't fully compatible with jQuery mobile, so revert it to 1.7.1.

This is how I add the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" media="all" />
```

You could try to change it to that (you can keep the link though).